# After assigning static IP to my ESP32 server doesn't respond anymore

Tags: c++, server, arduino, client, esp32

So I've got ESP32 acting as a server, and when calling http://IP_OF_ESP32:7777/SOMETEXT my code enables me to view the text written after the slash, the problem is that after assigning static IP to my ESP32 it doesn't work anymore here's my code

```
#include <WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "Inovec1";
const char* password =  "ccb255fd8f52";

WiFiServer server(7777);

IPAddress local_IP(192, 168, 121, 100);
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 1, 1);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 0, 0);
IPAddress primaryDNS(8, 8, 8, 8);
IPAddress secondaryDNS(8, 8, 4, 4);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.config(local_IP,gateway,subnet,primaryDNS, secondaryDNS);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(100);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  String message;
  while(client.available()){
    char c = client.read();
    message += c;
  }
  String command = getCommand(message);
  if(command.length()>0)
    Serial.println(command);
}

String getCommand(String s){
  String toFind1 = "GET /";
  String toFind2 = " HTTP";
  int start = s.indexOf(toFind1)+toFind1.length();
  int end = s.indexOf(toFind2);
  return s.substring(start,end);
}
```

Comment: What IP does your PC have?

Comment: Well definitely not the same

Comment: So other question if you don't want to answer: are you sure the Subnet you are using for es ESP is reachable from your PC? And hast the router the same subnet settings?

Comment: Not really sure what that means ...
IPv4 192.168.0.101
Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0
Def. Gateway 192.168.0.1
Router : 192.168.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as a first try give your ESP a IP address within the address range of your PC.

```
IPAddress local_IP(192, 168, 0, 10);
```

If that works ( I assume there is no other device with that address)
your problem is not the firmware/program but your routing.
(Routing, Subnets and so on is a topic on its own)

Answer (score 0):

Try this sketch, Ip Adress have to be in the same subnet.

```
#include <WiFi.h>

const char* ssid     = "yourSSID";
const char* password = "yourPWD";

IPAddress local_IP(192, 168, 1, 139);
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 1, 1);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);
IPAddress primaryDNS(8, 8, 8, 8);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);



  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  if (!WiFi.config(local_IP, gateway, subnet, primaryDNS)) { //just one DNS and Configuration after connect
    Serial.println("STA Failed to configure");
  }
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected!");
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.print("ESP Mac Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.macAddress());
  Serial.print("Subnet Mask: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.subnetMask());
  Serial.print("Gateway IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.gatewayIP());
  Serial.print("DNS: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.dnsIP());
}

void loop()
{

}
```